# Update values in a global dictionary from a PySpark UDF

Tags: pyspark, global-variables, user-defined-functions

I have a User Defined Function (UDF) that adds a new column to a spark dataframe but it's a little slow.

The UDF calculates the edit distance between user input and a list of correctly spelled words and I was hoping to speed it up by storing the user input and the closest word match in a global dictionary. The idea is to reference the global dictionary first before spending time calculating scores for all the words again.

I'm new to Spark/PySpark so I don't know all the correct terms, but from what I've read it sounds like the executors don't keep track of global variables across threads (or something). I also read about Broadcast variables but I think those are passed as inputs and Accumulators only allow numeric data.

Here's some sample code I'm working with currently:

```
def guess_word(user_entry):
    user_entry= user_entry.upper().strip()

    # Check if the best match has already been calculated from a previous row, 
    # if not, calculate scores and return the one with the lowest score
    if user_entry not in global_dict:
        scores = {}
        # Calculate scores against every word
        for word in word_dataset:
            word= word.upper().strip()
            if word not in scores:
                scores[word] = distance(user_entry, word)
            else:
                continue
        # Get the word with the lowest score (aka best match)
        word_guess, score = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])[0]

        # Update the global dictionary
        global_dict[user_entry] = (word_guess,score)

    else:
        word_guess = global_dict[user_entry]

    return word_guess


global_dict = {}

guess_word_udf = udf(lambda x: guess_word(x), StringType())

user_data = user_data.withColumn('word_guess', guess_word_udf('user_entry'))
```

After running this code, global_dict is always empty after running this code. Is it possible to...

I just realized I don't need the dictionary after the UDF finishes running and this question is now pointless :D